# Delete values occurring x number of times from character vector (R)

Tags: r

I am new to R and would like to delete values occurring x number of times from a character vector. For example, if you have a character vector: x = c("cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog") 
I would like to delete anything that occurs more than twice. How would I code this?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your example string is unclear. Do you mean "cat, cat, cat, dog, dog" ? Or "cat cat cat dog dog" ? Or a character vector, `c("cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog")` ?

Answer (score 2):

Using sapply:-

```
mystring <- c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "eagle")
counts <- sapply(unique(mystring), function(x) length(mystring[mystring==x]))
newstring <- mystring[counts[mystring] < 3]
newstring
# [1] "cat"   "cat"   "eagle"
```

Comment: Good answer assuming by "string", they mean "character vector".

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Changed to use `table(string)` only once.
Assuming you mean a character vector, you could use `table` although it is hard to give you a definitive answer without some representative data:

```
string <- c("cat","cat","cat","dog", "dog","pig")

tab_string <- table(string)
string[string %in% names(tab_string[tab_string<=2])]
#[1] "dog" "dog" "pig"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rle to count the number of repeated observations.

```
#string with repeats
string <- c("cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "beat", "beat", "beat")

#number of repeats for each string
count.repeats <- data.frame(unclass(rle(string)))

#get the string values that repeat more than 2
repeats <- as.character(count.repeats[count.repeats$lengths > 2, "values"])

#subset the original string to remove the stuff that repeats more than twice
string <- string[!(string %in% repeats)] 

#output
> string
[1] "dog" "dog"
```

Since your reproducible example is not great, it's hard to know if the strings are ordered by name. RLE will find the repeat occurences if they're next to each other in the string. It would be simple to sort your string by name before applying RLE so that all of the repeats are next to each other.

Comment: @Moneeb Bajwa - Did this answer work for you? And the below several answers also? If so, you should accept them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ave` to the rescue:

```
mystring <- c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "eagle")
mystring[ave(seq_along(mystring),mystring,FUN=length) <= 2]
#[1] "cat"   "cat"   "eagle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(mystring) %>% 
      add_count(mystring) %>%
      filter(n <=2) %>% 
     .$mystring
#[1] "cat"   "cat"   "eagle"
```

#### data

```
mystring <- c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "eagle")
```